# How should we implement moving for object types?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm reading about move semantic in C++11 and now I'm trying to understand the implementation of the move constructor. Suppose that we have the following class:

```
struct A {
    A(){ }
    virtual ~A(){ }
    A(const A&&){ }
};

struct B{
    int i;
    A a;
    virtual ~B(){ }
    B(const B&& b){
        i = b.i;
        i = 0;
        //How to move a??
    }
};
```

My question is how to invoke the `A`'s move constructor inside `B`'s one body? I'd use `std::swap`, but looking for it I found some [description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/). The arguments are of the ***lvalue*** reference type, so it has nothing to do with move semantic. What to do?

Comment: Why would you take an object by const rvalue reference?

Comment: `i = 0;` should be removed

Comment: @M.M Why? Couldn't you explain it a bit? I thought we should erase all bits of source.

Comment: `i` is the destination. maybe you meant `b.i = 0;` to "erase" the source. However that is not necessary unless it would be important to the logical state of a `B`

Comment: @M.M Yes, exactly. I meant `b.i = 0`. So why isn't that necessary? I though that if we didn't set it to 0 it wouldn't be moving.

Comment: what is achieved by setting it to `0` ?

Comment: @M.M Just setting all underlying bits of `b.i` to 0. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. If it makes sense to you, that's fine, it's your code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
B(B&& b)
  : i(b.i)
  , a(std::move(b.a))
{
}
```

Note the argument is no longer `const` (it never should have been), and all initialization can be done using the *initialization list* for optimal efficiency.

Comment: But in that case we don't set source values to `nullptr` or something else... I mean to perform the moving, not copying. I'm a bit confused by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/4671213) answer, where he sets the source to `nullptr `explicitly.

Comment: @stella: You don't need to do that.